# Laravel 9 - DB::rollBack() how to perform this 2 times?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, save, laravel-9

So, tittle cover a lot of this. Mycode saving more than one item at one click. Lets say we saving recipe or prescription (you named it). It cover drugs that somebody needed. I want save it (items) in one click including Name of the drug store. And **my problem is when at second loop (at *detailed_drug*) it got error, i need rollback first successfull drug at database**.

My JSON :

```
{
  "drug_store" : "DRG-2022070001",
  "street" : "Mataram Street, Malioboro, Yogyakarta",
  "date" : "28-12-2022 12:16:58",
  "status" : "RECIPE",
  "detailed_drug" : // here detailed_drug
  [
    {
      "drug_id" : "ITM-00001",
      "drug_name" : "acyclovir capsule",
      "exp_date" : "2022-12-09",
      "qty" : "2"
    },
    {
      "drug_id" : "ITM-00001",
      "drug_name" : "amiodarone tablet",
      "exp_date" : "2022-10-19",
      "qty" : "5"
    }
  ]
}
```

(I already know how to save (drug store etc) but when got error (at *detailed_drug*) i want rollback previous successfull data at database)

```
DB::connection('db_name')->beginTransaction();
$detailedRecipe= []; //for drugs or items.
$countDetail = $request->detailed; // lets pretend we have 2 drugs.

for($i=0;$i<$countDetail;$i++){

   $data = new Recipe();
   $data->drug_name = $request->drug_name;
   ...
   (etc)
   ...
   $success = $data->save();

   if(!$success) {
      DB::connection('db_name')->rollBack();
       return response()->json(['success' => false,'message' => 'Error message ... ']);
   }
}

DB::connection('db_name')->commit();
```

Comment: When you do `rollBack()` it should roll back everything that happened from when you started the transaction, which includes everything saved within the loop. I'm not clear on wexactly what the problem is

Comment: @apokryfos in my database first Item not roll back the second one is. Did i wrote wrong code ??

Comment: Could you share all the code instead and maybe the exact error message?

Comment: @JohnZwarthoed @apokryfos i solve my problem ` DB::connection('db_name') ` was the problem i got wrong database name. Suppose be Database B but i call Database A. Thanks for guide.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Silly of me. I call wrong database name. `DB::connection('database_A')` suppose to be `DB::connection('database_B')`.